# how to remodel the cell value from number with Millions to actual number?

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Please see the screencap - how to change the millions into actual number for further visualization?

[image: See]

Also seems the number in the growth_% column is not making sense too....this is the dataset I download from some data playground for test.

I tried what I found but not working...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a pair of lists you can use as a lookup table.

eg:

***Source***
[image]

```
let
    Source =Table.FromRecords( 
        {[Revenue="32.4 Million"],
        [Revenue= "10.6 Million"],
        [Revenue = "14.7 Thousand"]},
        type table[Revenue=text]),

//create the lookup table
    x = {"Hundred","Thousand","Million"},
    y = {2,3,6},

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Real", 
        each Number.From(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Revenue]," ")) *  
        Number.Power(10, y{List.PositionOf(x, Text.AfterDelimiter([Revenue]," "))}), type number)

in 
    #"Added Custom"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: I copied your code into create new DAX table but it give me error...which part should I change to suit my table?

Comment: @JCsushiguy It is M, not DAX. You modify your power query code.

Comment: @JCsushiguy So far as integrating into your own code, you'll need to figure that out. I showed you a technique. You add a custom column and then decide whether you want to retain or delete the original column. Again, this is a Power Query solution (which is in your tags), not a DAX solution. You will need to edit the Table Reference, and possibly the column name to suit your actual data.

Comment: @JCsushiguy If you post a question in the future, I suggest you familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I don't quite understand your solution - I try to use split column to numeric and text column, then add 0x6 to column, but how to fullfil column with 'billion'? how to do it in conditional column?

Comment: @JCsushiguy Using my solution, you would merely add `Billions` and `9` to the Lists. But if you don't understand it, I can't remedy that in this forum. You would have to educate yourself regarding Power Query and its M Code. If you cannot, I suggest you delete this question and post a new one ***in accordance with the guidelines for this forum*** *(linked to in my previous comment)* so that your question is clear.

Comment: Ok i found the solution, simply use M code in custom column:
Make a Custom Column with:

=
if Text.Contains([Revenue],"Million") then 
 (Number.FromText(Text.Replace([Revenue], " Million", "")) * 1000000)
else 
 (Number.FromText(Text.Replace([Revenue], " Billion", "")) * 1000000000)

Comment: @JCsushiguy Which is the same principle as I demonstrated, although in a less flexible format.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Custom Column with:

```
=
if Text.Contains([Revenue],"Million") then 
    (Number.FromText(Text.Replace([Revenue], " Million", "")) * 1000000)
else 
    (Number.FromText(Text.Replace([Revenue], " Billion", "")) * 1000000000)
```